# Install (MSI) won't install properly over old version

Tags: windows-installer

I have already looked at [Why doesn't my new Windows Installer file (MSI) install properly over an older version of the MSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013475/why-doesnt-my-new-windows-installer-file-msi-install-properly-over-an-older-v)
But that diden't help me.

I have a program (plugin to Office) which is installed by a setup package (MSI)

Originally the plugin and setup projects was made in Visual Studio 2005. The solution is now moved to Visual Studio 2010.
When I make a new MSI and try to install it over an older version the new version won't work before I make a repair using Add Remove Programs->Modify Installation->Repair
The new version installs perfectly if I remove the old version first.

It's important for us that the new MSI is able to remove the old version and install the new version smoothly because it is used by several users with no computer experience

The RemovePreviousVersion is set to True. I have upgraded the version from 3.1.1 to 4.0.0 and in that proces accepted a new ProductCode.
In Orca I have set the Reinstallmode to amus, but nothing seems to help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you said the upgrade works if run a repair for the new version? This situation could appear when both packages have shared components, i.e. duplicate GUIDs for your package components. To best method to track this down is to create a verbose log of the installation so we can analyze it.

During the repair there is no conflict with the older version, as it has already been removed and the components from the package are installed correct, this is why after that the plugin works.

Can you create a verbose log so we can have a look over it?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. It is correct that the upgrade works fine if I run a repair for the new version. I have made verbose logs of both of the installations. It can be downloaded here http://download.ditmer.dk/klu/Installlogs.zip

Comment: The log shows a component with the following GUID is shared by both versions of your application:  {1BB1F0AD-8476-42BE-A165-9116EEDCB560} . I recommend you generate a new GUID for this component in the package for the new version and test the upgrade again.

Comment: What happened was this, the component being shared by both of the, the new version skipped its installation, but then the uninstall of the older version was removing the shared component due to a bug in Windows Installer, so you were ending up with the missing resources. This is why after a repair everything was working correctly. Generating a new GUID should fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I have been away for the Easter. I have made a new GUID as recommended but unfortunately it dosent seem to help.

Comment: Can you post another log, created for the new installation package? Also is the problem present on other machines where an upgrade takes place? It is very important that the machine is clean, i.e. no repeated tests.

Comment: There's a new log here: download.ditmer.dk/klu/Installlog_new.zip. The problem is tested on numerous machines - on Windows 7 and on Windows XP. Most of the test takes place on an virtual XP machine which is reset before every test.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, the second log presents no visible issues, so the upgrade should be installed correctly. To get more details we need the verbose log created when the OS triggers the automatic repair. To create this log you need to activate global logging, as explained here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545723

Comment: There's a verbose log made from the repair here: download.ditmer.dk/klu/verboseLog.zip

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get more details from the log, but could find much info. However, I found another method to detect the reason of the repair. To get more information about the cause of the on demand install, open the Event Viewer ("Start -> Run", "eventvwr.msc") and look under the Application node for "MsiInstaller" log messages of the form:

> Event Type: Warning
>   Event Source: MsiInstaller
>   Event ID: 1001
>   Description:
>   Detection of product '{000C1109-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}', feature 'Example' failed during request for component '{00030829-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'

The message and the GUIDs will of course be different on your machine. You can then check the GUIDs in your project to see which component triggers the repair.

Answer (score 0):

By editing msi with Orca Tool, it may be solved your problem.

First I removes the existing products, by setting the sequence number of RemoveExistingProducts after InstallValidate and before InstallInitialize under the InstallExcecuteSequence tab.

Thanks, Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

you should tell us more. Are you exchanging version-number, product-, component-, upgrade- and Package-codes? Which software are you using?

Normally you are keeping upgrade codes the same within a product.
You need to specify the version numbers in the upgrade-table including the old/current upgrade codes.

depending where are you schedule the **RemoveExistingProducts** and if you keeping the component codes, i could be that some old components are not replaced.

i schedule the event always after **InstallInitialize**.

Check if the action **FindRelatedProducts** is called.

In [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829375/why-do-i-need-to-specify-a-new-guid-for-a-version-upgrade-in-wix/15829783#15829783) you can find a sample using WIX.